# Convert complex Java object to json with gson.toJsonTree

Tags: java, json, object, recursion, gson

I need to convert a java object (called org) to json format.
The object (DTO ) is a bit complex, because it contains a list of objects of the same class and which in turn can also contain more objects of the same class ( built recursively). When I passing the object to gson.toJsonTree method it seems to fail (there isnt any error), but it seems that the method does not like complex objects). If I set to null the list of objects of the first object everything works fine. I can not modify the class, only the method that makes json.

```
JsonElement jsonUO = null;
jsonUO =  gson.toJsonTree(org,OrgDTO.class);
jsonObject.add("ORG", jsonUO)

public class OrgDTO implements Serializable{
    private String id;
    ......
    private List sucesores;

    public OrgDTO(){
        this.sucesores = new ArrayList();
    }
    .....
}
```

Comment: so what json did it create?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a little bit late for the questioner, however I share my answer in case someone else face similar issue:

You'll need to create a helper class that does the json serialization. It should implement the JsonDeserializer:

```
public class OrgDTOJsonSerializer implements JsonDeserializer<OrgDTO> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(OrgDTO src, Type type, JsonSerializationContext jsc) {
        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();

        jsonObject.addProperty("id", src.getId());

        /// Build the array of sucesores (whatever it means!)
        JsonArray sucesoresArray = new JsonArray();
        for (final OrgDTO obj: src.getSucesores()) {
              JsonObject succJsonObj = serialize(obj, type, jsc);
              sucesoresArray.add(succJsonObj);
        }

        jsonObject.add("sucesores", sucesoresArray);

        return jsonObject;
    }
}
```

Then you'll need to register it in gson before attempting to serialize any object of that type:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(OrgDTO.class, new OrgDTOJsonSerializer());
```